# Create assembly With PERMISSION_SET = unsafe throws an exception

Tags: sqlclr

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [RA.VantagePoint.Clr.Core]
FROM 0x[Assembly binary]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

dbo is a syadmin and an owner, I am getting the following error:
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user XXXX (the user is the DB dbo)

this is a sql 2008R2 CS named instance
I am setting the database TrustWorthy to ON

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a long-term database (that is, one that's been around a while), one possibility for this error is that the Windows domain account to which the "dbo" database identity was originally mapped no longer exists. You might be able to determine if this is the problem by running the following in sys.databases:

```
SELECT name, suser_sname(owner_sid) FROM sys.databases
```

If the second column is null, the described problem may be at hand.

The information for this notion came from [this post on the MSDN forums.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlservicebroker/thread/28699c94-4d1b-43f2-bcfb-a95152ca226b)

Comment: I dont see how is this related

Comment: The article explained the possibility rather well. Basically, the process to invoke your assembly creation above will (eventually) verify mapping of the user associated with the dbo to a Windows account, and if that account has (over time, for whatever reason) changed or been deleted, the attempt to query the information will fail and generate the error you are seeing. I'm suggesting the possibility that may be what's happening in your case.